# Flutter: TabBar overflows bottom of AppBar when labels are enabled

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I have the following TabBar (I've used flexibleSpace to remove the padding an empty AppBar would put above the TabBar and SafeArea such that the TabBar doesn't appear under the android status bar):

```
home: DefaultTabController(
                length: 3,
                child: Scaffold(
                    appBar: AppBar(
                        flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                              children: [
                                  TabBar(
                                      indicatorColor: Color(0xfffffffe),
                                      tabs: [
                                          Tab(
                                              text: "Diary",
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.book),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(
                                              text: "Charts",
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
                                          ),
                                          Tab(
                                              text: "Settings",
                                              icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                                          )
                                      ],
                                  ),
                              ],
                          ),
                        ),
                    ),
                    body: TabBarView(
                        children: [
                            Diary(),
                            Charts(),
                            Settings(),
                        ],
                    )
                )
            ),
```

It looks like this when rendered:
[image]

How can I avoid the bottom overflow while still maintaining the safe area and flexibleSpace?

Comment: Why do you want to keep the flexibleSpace ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wrap your `TabBar` in an `Expanded` widget it should solve your problem

```
AppBar(
            flexibleSpace: SafeArea(
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Expanded(
                    child: TabBar(
                      indicatorColor: Color(0xfffffffe),
                      tabs: [
                        Tab(
                          text: "Diary",
                          icon: Icon(Icons.book),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: "Charts",
                          icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),
                        ),
                        Tab(
                          text: "Settings",
                          icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Let me know how this works for you.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the SafeArea and the Column should fix the problem:

```
      appBar: AppBar(
        flexibleSpace: TabBar(
          indicatorColor: Color(0xfffffffe),
          tabs: [
            Tab(text: "Diary",
                icon: Icon(Icons.book),),
            Tab(text: "Charts",
                icon: Icon(Icons.insert_chart),),
            Tab(text: "Settings",
                icon: Icon(Icons.settings),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
```